# How to get cells value from previous visible row in excel formulas

Tags: excel, filter, formulas

Is it possible to write a formulas in `Excel`,to calculate value based on the previous visible row?

By applying a `Filter` on the columns, the previous visible row changes but the usual formals does not consider visibility of the previous row, so the result does not change by applying filters. For example:

Let's original values of the spreadsheet cells be:

```
   A | B | C | D 
1: 5   3   1
2: 9   1   1
3: 2   3   0  
4: 7   8   1   =A3-B4 equals 2-8=-6
```

Now assume that we make a filter on `C` column to hide the third row so we have

```
   A | B | C | D 
1: 5   3   1
2: 9   1   1
4: 7   8   1   =A3-B4 is still equals -6 but I want to get: 9-8=1
```

Is it possible to get such a formulas? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you willing to use a *Helper* column??

Comment: @Ormoz Have you tried `offset`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this formula

`=LOOKUP(2,1/SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A$1,ROW(A$1:A3)-ROW(A$1),0)),A$1:A3)-B4`

The `SUBTOTAL/OFFSET` part returns a 1 or zero for each value in column A depending on whether it's visible or not, `LOOKUP` finds the last 1 (equivalent to the last visible value) and gives that value.

Comment: Thanks! Here's a table version to get previous visible & non-blank value for a column with a header of "A": `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET([[#Headers],[A]],1+ROW(OFFSET([[#Headers],[A]],1,0,ROW()-ROW([A])))-(ROW([[#Headers],[A]])+1),0)),OFFSET([[#Headers],[A]],1,0,ROW()-ROW([A]))),[@A])` (For those who don't know, you can convert a range into a table by pressing ctrl-t.)